# How to get website to load without clicking on the header

Tags: javascript, html

As of now I have to click on google to load google. Is there a way to just automatically load google without clicking on the title. I have tried removing the title and it will say unidentified and I click on that it will take me too google.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="id01"></div>
<script>
var myArray = [
   {
 "display": "google",
    "url":"https://google.com
},

 ]
 myFunction(myArray);
 function myFunction(arr) {
var out = "";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += '<a href="' + arr[i].url + '">' + arr[i].display + '</a><br>';
}
document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "myTutorials.txt";

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
     myFunction(myArr);
       }
    };

     xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();

     </script>

      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: You're looking for the `location` property.

Comment: call `location.href = www.google.com` after your event?